# Flutter IOS build error - "select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor."

Tags: ios, flutter

The following error is displayed when attempting to build on an IOS device:
As shown in the picture below, the Signing setting in Xcode is well done.
Can you tell me the cause and solution of this?

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Signing for "GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/home_1/StudioProjects/Example%20Project/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj


Error (Xcode): Signing for "DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/home_1/StudioProjects/Example%20Project/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj


Error (Xcode): Signing for "DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/home_1/StudioProjects/Example%20Project/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj


Error (Xcode): Signing for "gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/home_1/StudioProjects/Example%20Project/app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj
```

[image]

Comment: Check the link below to solve this issue, 
[POD Install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63180418/13080353)

Comment: I face the same problem and unfortunately pod install did not work for me.

Comment: I used Xcode 14 version and found that many people faced the same problem with this latest version. So I tried again after reverting to the previous version and succeeded.

Comment: This is coming from Flutter SDK, Flutter SDK is not compatible with latest version of xCode

Comment: Facing the same issue, as I needed to submit the build downgraded the xcode version and it worked

Comment: hey, no need to downgrade the Xcode, check my answer first, possibly it will solve the issue

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This happened to me today after switching to Xcode 14. Try adding this to your podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Don't forget to replace the `YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID` with your actual development Team ID which you can find in [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/account/#!/membership)

This will permanently fix the issue.

If you don't want to use the Team ID you can do this instead:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you have other `post_install` steps, for example `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)`, make sure to keep them

Comment: This worked for me but I had to keep this line:
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

Comment: I'd also check out these issues: 
[issue 1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111475)
[issue 2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402)

Comment: This fixed the issue.  What is causing this issue? Is the fix a workaround for an issue with flutter SDK or Xcode?

Comment: @Justin no it's not a flutter issue, it is related to Xcode. I'm a native(swift) developer myself and I've faced the same issue

Comment: I prefer this solution over the others, as this overcame the issue from Apple reviewers where they reject apps that have their pods' code signing skipped by using `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = NO`.

Answer (score 14):

I'm wondering when Apple is going to launch a new xCode version without breaking anything from previous ones!

Rants aside, this is how I fixed my **Flutter** project based on previous answers:

Open your awesome_flutter_project/ios/Podfile:

and replace these lines:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

for:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Mine worked only with your answer! The diff is: flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target). Thanks!

Comment: It did work well

Answer (score 9):

Just for everyone, who thinks the accepted solution is a hack, you are right. This is a known bug in the flutter framework which has been fixed in flutter 3.3.3 .

So I recommand everyone to upgrade to this version, if you are able/allowed to do so.

In case you can't upgrade to 3.3.3 then the accepted solution is your best bet ;)

Comment: worked for me after upgrading to 3.3.3

Answer (score 5):

It's a `Flutter framework` issue

Update `Flutter` version into `3.3.3`

Answer (score 4):

I also got this error after updating XCode to version 14.

Add the following to **ios > podfile**

[image]

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To get **YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID**: https://developer.apple.com/account/#!/membership/

This will permanently fix the issue.

If you don't want to use the Team ID you can do this instead:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by doing the following:

1. Open project on xCode
2. Open **Pods** and find out "GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn" and other three on **Pods > Target**
3. Select **Team** on **Signing & Capabilities**

Comment: you will be required to do this every time after pod install

Answer (score 1):

Open your `flutter` project in `Xcode`

> Pods -> Targets -> Signing & Capabilities -> Select Team

Select `Team` for `every Targets`

[image]

Comment: I simply tried running the app in xcode and then selected the development team for every lib it complained.

Comment: It can work for local build, when you don't modify config, but with CI/CD like fastlane it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I am using CodeMagic.io (CI/CD) and had this same problem, I found the issue to be the Xcode version: 14

I solved this at CodeMagic.io by doing this :

1. Go to the Workflow Editor
2. Go to 'Build'
3. Change the Xcode version: 13.4.1

If you are using another CI/CD try using Xcode version: 13.4.1

*It was mentioned to solve this you can also update your Flutter version to 3.3.3 however if like me this is not an option for you try using Xcode version 13.4.1*

Answer (score 1):

adding following code solved issue in Xcode 14 and flutter version 2.8

> ```
>         config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When I put the the suggested changes in the **pod** file and run the **flutter build ipa** command, I am getting a different **error**.

Error:

```
 In file included from /Volumes/Data/FlutterSDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.3/ios/Classes/FWFUIViewHostApi.m:5:
/Volumes/Data/FlutterSDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.9.3/ios/Classes/FWFUIViewHostApi.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
```

Comment: Me too, Did you get a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

For CI/CD, this is the only solution that worked for me.
Update `podfile`.

```
       target_is_resource_bundle = target.respond_to?(:product_type) && target.product_type == 'com.apple.product-type.bundle'
       target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
         if target_is_resource_bundle
           build_configuration.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
           build_configuration.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
           build_configuration.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY'] = '-'
           build_configuration.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = '-'
         end
       end
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

then go to the team drop list and select your team