# Flutter - Error (Xcode): Signing for "DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController" requires a development team - select a development team

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-update

Updated my `xcode` to `14.0`. After upgrading the `xcode`,  My `Flutter` project throwing the below error.

```
select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor
```

***Target > Signing & Capabilities > Team also already selected***

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Signing for "DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/rsoft/StudioProjects/salezrobot/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj

Error (Xcode): Signing for "DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/rsoft/StudioProjects/salezrobot/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, it was an underlying issue in the Flutter framework, which was fixed in **Flutter 3.3.3**, released on September 28th.

It is the first item in [the list of hotfixes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#333-sept-28-2022) that this version provides.

Try running `flutter upgrade` to make sure you are running the latest version of Flutter. If the issue persists, try a `flutter clean` and a manual `pod install` in your project's iOS folder.

Answer (score 4):

I found a temporary solution for this issue

Open your flutter project in `Xcode`

```
Pods -> Targets -> Signing & Capabilities -> Select Team
```

Select `Team` for each and every `Targets`

*Note :* The above steps you need to do whenever you take build. this is not a permanent solution

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: I'm also looking bro, If u find a solution ans me bro

Comment: Actually I found something that helped me finally. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711671/flutter-ios-build-error-select-a-development-team-in-the-signing-capabiliti

Answer (score 4):

This issue relates to XCode 14 pods signing.

To make everything work again, update your podfile with some content:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    # Add the line below
    target_is_resource_bundle = target.respond_to?(:product_type) && target.product_type == 'com.apple.product-type.bundle'

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|

      # And lines from here
      if target_is_resource_bundle
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY'] = '-'
        config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = '-'
      end
      # to here

    end
  end
end
```

Then run:

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods/ .symlinks Flutter/Flutter.podspec
pod install
pod repo update
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update `Flutter` version to `3.3.3`
See hot-fix notes [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#333-sept-28-2022)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `podfile`

> From

```
 post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

> To

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'your team id'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**or**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```