# exportArchive: Code signing "App.framework" failed

Tags: ios, flutter, fastlane

I am using `fastlane` to generate a build.

Here is my environment detail,

1. Flutter 3.7.6
2. XCode 14.2
3. Fastlane

Here is a some portion of my fastlane script,

```
//1. Using match to generate certificate and profile.[Code not shown here]

//2. Disabled automatic code singing
disable_automatic_code_signing(path: "Runner.xcodeproj")

//3. Setting code sign to manual
update_code_signing_settings(
      build_configurations: configuration,
      use_automatic_signing: false,
      profile_name: profileName,
      team_id: ENV['IOS_TEAM_ID'],
      code_sign_identity: "iPhone Distribution"
    ) 

//4. Running Flutter build iPa command without code signing. 
sh_on_root(command: "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin && flutter build ipa #{params} --no-codesign")

//5. Generating iPA
build_app(
      output_directory: "#{root_path}/build/ios",
      build_path: "#{root_path}/build/ios",
      archive_path: "#{root_path}/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive",
      export_method: method,
      scheme: env,
      configuration: configuration,   
      skip_build_archive: true,  
      workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
      export_options: {
        signingStyle: "manual",
        provisioningProfiles: profileMap,  
        teamID: ENV['IOS_TEAM_ID'],
        signingCertificate: "Apple Distribution",
        compileBitcode: false      
      } 
    )
```

During 5th step, I am getting error `Error Domain=IDEDistributionPipelineErrorDomain Code=0 "Code signing "App.framework" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Code signing "App.framework" failed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=View distribution logs for more information.}`

What I have already tried,

- Opened up XCode project and checked that all code sign related configurations are looking good. With same settings Archieve is working well from Xcode.
- Manually Firing `flutter build ipa` from terminal is working well.  I just need to add ExportOptions.plist file.
- Tried to tweak Podfile not to take up any code signing settings. [Reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711671/flutter-ios-build-error-select-a-development-team-in-the-signing-capabiliti)

Any suggestion would be helpful.

**Update**
Firing lane execution command from CD machine's terminal is working fine but when Jenkin is firing same command then it is causing issue of code signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, `build_app` was not able to access keychain and that's why it was showing error of code signing.
I used `unlock_keychain` with the appropriate parameter and it started working.